# Fabric Installation On Ubuntu

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is there an installation manual for Hyperledger Fabric?
The docs talk about sample codes only.
What are the components?
How can I install each component on a VM?
Do I have to use Docker?

Sawtooth was easy to install and it has much better documentation. There is only theory about Fabric.

Does someone have a good step-by-step installation on Ubuntu?

Comment: I think you should read the official documentation first: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io, and you must to use Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Working with Hyperledger Fabric, you will always hear about "fabric network". By network, it means there are more than one node involved, actually at least 2, an  orderer node and a peer node. That means, fabric is not a tool-like software. If you want to work on a single server or just your laptop, it requires docker to compose a virtual network.

Since Hyperledger Fabric version 1.2, I think the documentation is getting much better. [Build Your First Network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html) is a good start place. It downloads the docker images required, show you what to configure and finally bring up the fabric network. Enjoy!